# Defining the value of a private float in a different class and file

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine, private

```cs
public class LevelLighting
{
    public static float nightvisionFogIntensity;

    private static float auroraBorealisCurrentIntensity;
}
```

In C#

This is a small bit of the class in a code I'm referencing for my own, the value i want to change and implement is auroraBorealisCurrentIntensity, but it is private so it tells me there is no definition for it in the class. Is there any way I can use this value even though it is set as private?

I'm not able to edit the code above, only my own code that needs to reference the code above.

```cs
LevelLightning.nightvisionFogIntensity = 1f;
```

This works, since nightvisionFogIntensity is public

```cs
LevelLighting.auroraBorealisCurrentIntensity = 1f;
```

This doesn't work, since auroraBorealisCurrentIntensity is private.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Usually there is a reason why things are `private` (encapsulated): you shall not be able to modify the value. Of course you can use reflection etc but why?

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost I need to warn you that changing private fields that are not supposed to be changed is dangerous and can lead to unexpected behavior of the target object.

That said if you still want to do it the only way I see it is using **reflection**.
I prepared a little example. Here is a version of your class that has a method `PrintBorealisValue()` to help us show the result after the change:

```
public class LevelLightening
{
    public static float nightvisionFogIntensity;

    private static float auroraBorealisCurrentIntensity;

    public static void PrintBorealisValue()
    {
            Console.WriteLine(auroraBorealisCurrentIntensity);
    }
}
```

Now let's instantiate an object of this class and change it's private variable:

```
LevelLightening.PrintBorealisValue(); // prints "0"

var borealisField = typeof(LevelLightening)
                            .GetField("auroraBorealisCurrentIntensity", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
// will be a good idea to check "borealisField" for null here
borealisField.SetValue(null, 3.14f); 

LevelLightening.PrintBorealisValue(); // prints "3.14"
```

It is also worth noting that using reflection is usually slower than doing the same thing without reflection (which is kind of obvious).

Comment: For a `static` field the `var light = new LevelLightening()` is redundant.. you can just pass `null` for the object instance `borealisField.SetValue(null, 3.14f);`

Comment: Yes, I didn't give it much of a thought, but you are right. Will update my answer so it will be more accurate.

Comment: The problem though is that I am unable to edit the class since the anti-cheat of the game would go nuts if I change anything in its assembly. I can edit the value of the nightvisionFogIntensity for example since it's public but not the auroraBorealisCurrentIntensity because it's private, so is there a workaround to this, to let me change the value of the private float? Thanks

Comment: @refreshyt I gave you the way how to do it without changing the class itself. I changed it only to add a method to print the change, but you can totally ignore this part.

Comment: ```public class LevelLighting
{
    public static float nightvisionFogIntensity;

    private static float auroraBorealisCurrentIntensity;
}```
this part cant be changed at all nothing can be added to it, that's the problem, sorry if i don't make any sense i'm new to C#

Comment: @refreshyt forget about this class! Just add these 2 lines `var borealisField = typeof(LevelLightening).GetField("auroraBorealisCurrentIntensity", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);  
borealisField.SetValue(null, 3.14f); ` and after them the value will be changed!

Comment: @refreshyt what dimitar.d is trying to tell you .. you can use reflection from just **anywhere**! The lines this answer provides are not supposed to be added to the original class at all

Comment: thanks a lot @dimitar.d and derHugo i was just not understanding, now it works thanks a lot for your time!